# Setting user_id for post creation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble setting the user_id on the creation of a post

```
def create

  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.user_id = session[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get is specifically `undefined method 'username' for nil:NilClass` when redirected to the show action. A look at the database shows that no user_id is set.

I also tried passing the user_id as a hidden field. but this did not work either (a look at the logs showed the hidden field wasn't even being passed for some reason).

Would appreciate a point in the right direction,

Thank you !

EDIT: as requested here is the show controller

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    @original_id = params[:original_id]

    @comment = Comment.new
end

<%= form_for [:admin, @post] do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Below is the form

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

root 'posts#index'

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end

  resources :users, only: [:create]

  #Posts
  get "/meta", to: "posts#meta"

  #User Routes
  get "/signup", to: "users#new"
  get "/success", to: "users#index"

  #login Routes
  get "/login", to: "sessions#login"
  post "/sessions/login_attempt", to: "sessions#login_attempt"

  #session routes
  get "/sessions/home", to: "sessions#home"
  get "/sessions/logout", to: "sessions#logout"

  #admin routes
  #resources :posts, module: 'admin', except: [:show, :index]
  namespace :admin do 
    root 'posts#new'
    resources :posts, except: [:show, :index]
  end
```

Comment: Please post the show action of the controller

Comment: Do you have any kind of relationship between user and post?

Comment: yes user has many posts, post belongs to user

Comment: Please post more details: On what line do you get the exception?

Comment: post your form and show page code.

Comment: What is this controller's name? What are your routes?

Comment: class Admin::PostsController

Comment: What version of Rails?  Are you using strong_parameters?

Comment: 4 and yes I am using strong_parameters

Answer (score 3):

Inside of your create method add

```
@post = Post.build(params[:post])
@post.user_id = current_user.id
```

This will grab the current user id for the given post.

Comment: How do you know he has `current_user` method available?

Comment: If he does not, he'll eventually need it to track users by session.

Comment: Cant I just use session to track my users...?

Comment: @Melbourne2991 yes but sometimes you need to track a user by their current session so that is when current_user method comes in handy. Of course you will need to define current user in your application_controller.rb file

Comment: Hm still a bit confused, if session[user_id] doesnt track the current session, what does it track

Comment: session[:user_id] does track the current user. I was just saying you could assign the current session to the current_user and then you could use the current_user throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a has_many relationship between posts and users, why not do something like this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@post = @user.posts.new(params[:post])
```

The params might be different but this is the 'more ruby' way do do things. It explicitly notes the relationships between the two models. The above code should be in the #new action and then you would save it within the create action.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot now but the issue was I was using session[:id] as opposed to session[:user_id]

Set in my sessions controller

```
def login_attempt
authorized_user = RegisteredUser.authenticate(params[:username_or_email],params[:login_password])
    if authorized_user
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      flash[:notice] = "Wow Welcome again, you logged in as #{authorized_user.username}"
      redirect_to(:action => 'index', :controller => "users")
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
      render "login"    
    end   
end
```